# perf report -- symbol names don't fit on the screen

Tags: linux, redhat, perf

Is there some way to tell `perf report` to condense the symbol names shown?

I'm unable to read the method name but I can see only the beginning of what might be the class name or what might be the return type (even when using a font of size 7).

perf 3.10
Redhat 7.7

Comment: Can you show the output of `perf report`?

Comment: @Arnabjyoti_Kalita I'm not certain, that I'm allowed to do this. Just thing about a flat_map of a mapping of pointer to flyweight of flat_set of pointer.
Displaying the symbols in the mangled way helped.

Answer (score 1):

using the `--no-demangle` option for `perf report` helped to make the output fit on the terminal used.